# How to start stop QCamera?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qcamera

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "unistd.h"
#include <qdebug.h>
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
ui->setupUi(this);
m_scene = new QGraphicsScene;
m_item = new QGraphicsVideoItem;

ui->graphicsView->setScene(m_scene);
ui->graphicsView->scene()->addItem(m_item);

camera = new QCamera(QCameraInfo::defaultCamera());
camera->setViewfinder(m_item);
camera->setCaptureMode(QCamera::CaptureVideo);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
delete ui;
}
// On Start Button
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
camera->start();
}
// On Stop Button
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
camera->stop();
}
```

I have above code to stream USB camera. Camera stream does not start on pressing "Start Button". Camera stream is displayed when I first press stop button and then start button.

I can not understand this behaviour. How to make it work correctly?

Comment: Have you checked the `QCamera::State`, the `QCamera::Status` and, if existing, the errorString when it fails for pressing the "Start Button"?

Comment: The camera status just before camera->start() is  "QCamera::UnloadedStatus". After camera->start() the camera status is "QCamera::LoadingStatus"

Comment: I would try to trigger `load()`, wait for the camera status to be `LoadingStatus` and then trigger `start()`. The QCamera doc states, that "It's not necessary to explcitly load the camera, unless unless the application have to read the supported camera settings and change the default depending on the camera capabilities". Maybe this is the cause?